# How to print a table as ticket in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following table in a bootstrap modal and I am using a JQuery third-party library to print the table on the modal witch is:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikzaadi/jQuery.printElement/master/src/jquery.printelement.js

[image]

The following CSS styles were applied to the table:

```
td.ticket-product,
th.ticket-product {
    width: 75px;
    max-width: 75px;
}

wrap-break-word-in-css */
td.ticket-qty,
th.ticket-qty {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

td.ticket-price,
th.ticket-price {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

td.ticket-sub-total,
th.ticket-sub-total {
    width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

My issue is when I want to print the table, the print window does not respect the margins.
The idea of this is to have similar to:

https://parzibyte.github.io/ticket-js/2/

[image]

Any help here is welcome

Comment: Your problem is that there is too much space between the columns ? Table are special DOM element with `display` property that does not fit the `width` if all columns has `width` property because it adapts to fill the `width` of the table. **You should simply reduce the `width` of your table.**

Comment: I reduce the width but that does not works

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: the print window does not respect the margins after reduce the width